# awaitTxConfirmed not returning

Tags: plutus

Under what conditions does `awaitTxConfirmed` not return?

It stopped returning since I updated my `cabal.project` file to make use of the latest plutus tag `plutus-starter-devcontainer/v1.0.7`. It worked with `plutus-starter-devcontainer/v1.0.6`.

The changes that had to be made were as trivial as changing `ByteString` to `BuiltinByteString`, `mustForgeValue` to `mustMintValue` etc.

The test output looks like:

```
...
Slot 00003: W1: TxSubmit: b7c6004fe8f4b8cdf94c9b4b3260f4bc60ae4c9fa6ec9d64e4b8f5e4e9c83c5b
Slot 00003: SlotAdd Slot 4
Slot 00004: SlotAdd Slot 5
...
```

Comment: can you post your code where you are actually using `awaitTxConfirmed`?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is found in the [Plutus.Contract.Request](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/blob/master/plutus-contract/src/Plutus/Contract/Request.hs#L372) module of `plutus-contract`.

It says that: "If the transaction is never added to the ledger then 'awaitTxConfirmed' never returns".

Comment: You are right about the comment, but it doesn't explain the reason why `awaitTxConfirmed` would not return

Comment: `awaitTxConfirmed` won't return because if loops indefinitely. If you look at the implementation, it stops looping only when the status of the tx is something other than `Unknown`.

Comment: This doesn't explain it, since the `awaitTxConfirmed` isn't recursive

Comment: You see the `go` function inside `awaitTxConfirmed`? It's recursive no?

Comment: Ok,  you are right about the recursion... But still, it doesn't tell why it may loop indefinitely :) I'd like to believe that the answer might have more to do with general blockchain documentation and not what can be discerned from code. I might be wrong though